# select group_concat vs group_concat on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm analyzing a few queries and have noticed some interesting results when trying to extract multiple fields from different tables based on a `user_id`. Consider the following tables:

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subscription_id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| expires                | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created                | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| modified               | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to `GROUP_CONCAT` all of a user's subscriptions when fetching users. Currently this method works for one field:

```
SELECT u.id,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.subscription_id)
    FROM subscriptions s
    WHERE s.user_id = u.id
) AS subscription_ids
FROM users u
LIMIT 10
```

And I can add all of the fields with different `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT`s. However this method is **very slow** with any real number of rows due to MySQL joining the `subscriptions` table for every field. Is there a way that I can `GROUP_CONCAT` all of the fields at once when listing users?

I've tried a `LEFT JOIN` method:

```
SELECT
    u.id AS user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.subscription_id) AS subscription_ids
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s
    ON s.user_id = u.id
LIMIT 10
```

However, that appears to concatenate **all** of the subscription_ids. I'm a bit stumped why the `LEFT JOIN` would do that. But I'm surprised there doesn't appear to be an easy way to concatenate a list of fields from a different table.

Comment: On your second query, have you tried `GROUP BY u.id`?

Comment: In both cases you use aggregate function without actually aggregating anything (by `GROUP BY`). But in the first case each time `GROUP_CONCAT` is invoked, its field of operation is limited by `s.user_id = u.id` criteria. In the second case, however, there's no such limitation.

Comment: That's done it. I need to read up on `GROUP_CONCAT` logic apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function and therefore needs to be applied with `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT
    u.id AS user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.subscription_id) AS subscription_ids
FROM 
    users u
    LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
    u.id
LIMIT 10
```